# Secure WebAPI via Global filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I found that I can secure all MVC `Controller`s in an MVC app by just adding the line

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

to `RegisterGlobalFilters`. My ApiControllers still have to be secured by manually adding the `[Authorize]` attribute. Is there a similar line that I can add to secure all my WebAPI `ApiController`s as well?

The `[Authorize]` Attribute of WebAPI is in `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, but I did not succeed with

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

which throws the error

> The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're registering against the `GlobalFilterCollection` in your question, but that applies to MVC. You need to register the `AuthorizeAttribute` in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

        // Other web api config rules...
    }
}
```